# How to check for a variable existence by a private function in a php Class?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Here is a pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
class Test {

  protected  $myVar;

  public function __construct(){
      // get data from DB, returns null if not exist
      $this->myVar = getDataFromDatabase();
  }

  public function myFunc(){

       if(!$this->myVar){
           return response(['message' => 'data not found'],404);
       }

       // do other stuff
  }      
}
```

This code is working well. Now I want to declare a private function to check for the existence of a variable (To clean my code and use the function everywhere).

This is what I tried :

```
  public function myFunc(){

       $this->checkExistence();

       // do other stuff
  }  

  private function checkExistence(){
      if(!$this->myVar){
        return response(404);
      }
  }
```

But it is not working because I do not return the `$this->checkExistence();`!

And when I try to return it:

`return $this->checkExistence();`

It's working but the problem is when `$myVar` exists it is not hitting `// do other stuff` line because it is returning the whole function that makes sense!

How should I transfer this existence checking to private function!?

Comment: try  if($this->checkExistence()){...}else{...}

Comment: where do you call this function?

Comment: If you want to return a 404 response there, you could use the [abort()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-abort) method.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo  I am calling it in `myFunc` function. take a look at my second pseudo code.

Comment: @DeesOomens  you are right. But actually I want to  return  a json response with `404`  code.  Will update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return a response somewhere out of the controller you can always use the [`abort()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-abort) method. As the Laravel docs say:

> The abort function throws an HTTP exception which will be rendered by the exception handler.

The method accepts a response code, but also a Response class (as you can [see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L40)). If you'd like to return a JSON response you could use the following code:

```
abort(response()->json([], 404));
```

Comment: I already doing this by : `return response([
                'message' => 'data not found'
            ], 404);`

Comment: And it's working well and returns HTTP Exception,  but when I put this code in a private function  it is not wotrking

Comment: What do you mean by not working? It isn't return a JSON response?

Comment: `public function myFunc(){  RETURN $this->checkExistence(); }` And `checkExistense()` return whatever you need.

Comment: @DeesOomens Sorry forgot to remove `return` from `myFunct` , Now its working but `abort` only accept `int` for the first arg and for the second accepts `string`, ERROR: `Object of class Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse could not be converted to int`

Comment: Now the problem is how to `abort` and return `json` simulatiously.

Comment: Ah you're using Laravel 5.5 or lower. In 5.6 or higher you can send a Response instance to the abort method.

Comment: I am using lumen! latest version! :)

Comment: Maybe try to override the abort method in a custom helpers file? I posted a link to the code in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw a (custom) exception, and handle the exception in myFunc();

```
  public function myFunc()
  {
       try {
           $this->checkExistence();
           // do other stuff
       } catch (\My\Namespace\ExistenceException $e) {
           //Handle error
           return response(404);
       }
  }  

  /**
  * @throws \My\Namespace\ExistenceException
  */
  private function checkExistence(): void
  {
      if(!$this->myVar){
        throw new \My\Namespace\ExistenceException;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Daan for the answer, I'm looking for cleaner code, can I transfer `try...catch` to `checkExistence` function?  and just call `checkExistence()`  in `myFunc` ?

Comment: And can I response json after Exception happens ?

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest for you would be an else clause in your private method. Code after return statement doesn't run, hence an "else" is mandatory in your case. Also, do try to typehint your $myVar to your constructor as well.

```
    public function __construct($myVar)
     {
        //assign here as you've done
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against returning response in your `checkExistence()` method. Instead, I would have that method return `true` or `false` and return the response in the `myFunc()`:

```
public function myFunc(){
    if (this->checkExistence()) {
        return response(404);
        // Or better yet, use: `abort(404);`
    }
    // do other stuff
}  

private function checkExistence(){
    return !$this->myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to check if the variable is false-ish (which in PHP includes bool(false) and NULL and emptystring and non-existing property and empty array and god knows what else), you want to check if the property exists, right? in which case, use `property_exists`, eg

```
  private function checkExistence(){
      if(!property_exists($this,'myVar'){
        return response(404);
      }
  }
```